# How To Ignore and error in Visual Studio WebTests

Tags: visual-studio, testing

I'm using Visual Studio to record some web tests. I'd like the test to pass (obviously), but it is failing because of something out of our control - so I'd like to surpress that failure.

One of our pages is using an API from a third party like say, let's pick on, facebook. (It's not facebook, but for sake of argument it is). Let's say that we're using the facebook open-graph api to do something or other, and one of their 1px gif files is not found because one of their developers made a typo in the filename. They don't know it's not found, and the API works perfectly with that request erroring out. I want to surpress the error in the web test upon loading mysite.com/index.aspx because it's an inconsequential error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn off the propety called "Analyze dependant request" for that specific request in your web test.
Not shure for of the property name, I got the french version of 2010.

Answer (score 1):

In English VS 2010 it is "Parse Dependent Requests"

Answer (score 0):

the problem with turning off the "Parse Dependant Requests" is that the page doesn't actually call them either. In a page that has many images you can clearly see that there is a significant difference in the response time of the page when you have dependant requests on or off.